# How to remove chart series by its index

Tags: javascript, html, teechart

I want to remove certain chart series by its index. In my case 'removeSeries' method removes series but not the correct index. So help me to do this, please.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance.....

regards,
sumesh

Comment: Which exact TeeChart version are you using: VCL/FMX, Java, .NET, ActiveX, PHP, HTML5, etc. Thanks in advance.

Comment: i am using TeeChart for JavaScript version v2013.10.22.1.5

Answer (score 0):

It works fine for me with the following code:

```
function draw() {
  Chart1=new Tee.Chart("canvas1");

  for (i=0; i<5; i++) {
    Chart1.addSeries(new Tee.Line(Chart1)).addRandom(25);
  }

  Chart1.removeSeries(Chart1.getSeries(2));

  Chart1.draw();
}
```

I see the series with index 2 (Series3) isn't present in the Chart:

[image]